# Host Symfony2 bundle on GitHub and install it with Composer

Tags: symfony, github, composer-php

### Background

I have created a [Symfony2 application hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweets). Now I want to make it a bundle instead of an application, in order to use it with Composer.

### What I've tried

I have created a new repository on GitHub named [AsyncTweetsBundle](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle), I think my vendor name should be `AlexisLefebvre` and the bundle name `AsyncTweetsBundle`. But I don't understand how to configure the <kbd>composer.json</kbd>file, here is the current content of the file:

```
{
    "name" : "alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "description" : "PHP Twitter reader for asynchronous reading",
    "keywords" : ["twitter", "reader", "bundle"],
    "homepage": "http://asynctweets.alexislefebvre.com/",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "authors" : [{
        "name" : "Alexis Lefebvre",
        "homepage": "http://alexislefebvre.com/",
        "role": "Developer"
    }],
    "require" : {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "0.5.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle" : ""
        }
    },
    "target-dir": "AlexisLefebvre/Bundle/AsyncTweetsBundle",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "0.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the base class of the bundle <kbd>AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle</kbd> :

```
<?php

namespace AlexisLefebvre\Bundle\AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

I have submitted this package on Packagist: [alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle).

So I created a Symfony2 installation and added this dependency:

```
composer create-project \
symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony2_AsyncTweetBundle --prefer-dist
cd symfony2_AsyncTweetBundle/
composer require alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle
```

The bundle is installed in `vendor/alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle/AlexisLefebvre/Bundle/AsyncTweetsBundle/AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle.php` but I can't use it.

### Problems

The bundle is installed in `vendor/alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle/AlexisLefebvre/Bundle/AsyncTweetsBundle/AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle.php`. Is it correct?

I added `new AlexisLefebvre\Bundle\AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle()` in <kbd>app/AppKernel.php</kbd> but if I run a command, eg. `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`, it throws an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AlexisLefebvre\Bundle\AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle' not found in .../symfony2_AsyncTweetBundle/app/AppKernel.php on line 20

What is the correct name for the bundle? Is the namespace `AlexisLefebvre` mandatory in the bundle's class name? Should I use `AlexisLefebvre` or `AlexisLefebvre\Bundle` as the base namespace? What is the correct value of `"target-dir"`. I didn't find any explanation of the links between the different parts of the <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file: `"name"`, `"autoload" : {"psr-0" : {}}` and `"target-dir"`.

I tried with `"autoload" : {"psr-4" : {...}}` (`psr-0` is deprecated for new projets) and it was even worse, the bundle didn't installed at all.

Comment: Just use the class name in AppKernel.php: new AlexisLefebvreAsyncTweetsBundle();  the psr-0 autoloading line takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Cerad I tried and the class is still not found.

Comment: Check vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php.  There should be an entry for your bundle.

Comment: Yes there is `'AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle'),`, which looks like the line for loading `DoctrineCacheBundle`, except it doesn't work for my bundle.

Comment: Your psr-0 line needs a trailing backslash.  Notice how the other entries in the autoload file end with \\? "AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle\\" : ""

Comment: Not all lines have trailing backslashes: `'Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineCacheBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/...'),`. I tried with `'AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '...'),` and the problem is still there.

Comment: I'm guessing a typo.  You are using psr-0 and not psr-4?

Comment: @Cerad yes I use `psr-0`.

Comment: No you are not.  At lease according to your github repository.  psr-0 requires the directories to actually exist.  psr-4 allows you to eliminate these directories.  If you have been making changes then perhaps consider updating your question with the proper code.  In particular, double check the path to your Bundle.php file.

Comment: @Cerad : I see `psr-0` in [`composer.json`](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle/blob/master/composer.json).

Comment: Right which is why you need to change it to psr-4.  The psr-0 loader is not able to find your classes.

Comment: @Cerad I don't understand why `psr-0` works for other bundles (e.g Doctrine fixtures bundle) and not for my bundle. I'll try `psr-4`.

Comment: @Cerad I switcher to [`psr-4`](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle/blob/b88d20aa6b1484e0da04fae038ceea0cafa8ea4c/composer.json) and I still can't load my bundle.

Comment: Consider updating your question with the latest files and error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for a PersonBundle under the Cerad namespace.

```
{
"name":        "cerad/person-bundle",
"type":        "symfony-bundle",
"description": "Symfony Cerad Person Bundle",
"keywords":    ["cerad","zayso"],
"homepage":    "http://github.com/cerad/PersonBundle",
"license":     "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "",
        "email": "",
        "homepage": "http://zayso.org",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Cerad\\Bundle\\PersonBundle\\": "" }
},
"target-dir": "Cerad/Bundle/PersonBundle"
}
```

The code gets installed under 
vendor\cerad\person-bundle\Cerad\Bundle\PersonBundle

I have a CeradPersonBundle.php file 
with a namespace of Cerad\Bundle\PersonBundle;

All the path and options are confusing.  I worked my way through it by having composer first load directly from github instead of packagist.  Easier to make changes to composer.json that way.

Comment: I have edited my question after you posted this answer. How do you add the bundle in `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: In my case, new CeradPersonBundle() does the trick.  The psr-0 line takes care of the autoloading issues.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your [packagist repository](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle) and your [github repository](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweets/tree/master/src/AsyncTweets/TweetBundle). It seems that the repository point by your package has no files. So, first try merging your files at these two locations.

Then, if you want to change your vendor name/namespace change namespace for every file for uniformity and for you already know how to create your own package.

Still you can look at [Creating your very own Composer Package](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package)
in case of confusion.

Comment: I thought that the bundle may load even if there was nothing in it. I'll add some files on the bundle.

Comment: All you need is a bundle file.  The problem is that you have swapped to using psr-4 and not psr-0.  Hence your class cannot be found.

Comment: I was able to require your package form packagist using composer and I successfully register it on my AppKernel with 
`new AlexisLefebvre\Bundle\AsyncTweetsBundle\AsyncTweetsBundle(),`
Untill now, everything works fine for me.

Comment: @SanThapa : wow, it works for me too, even if it doesn't match the namespace declared in `composer.json` or in the PHP bundle base class. I don't understand!

Comment: Namespace doesn't match? You have autoloaded your namespace from composer.json using psr-4 
`"AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle\\" : ""` and it is as your file namespace of bundle class. 
If you meant about folder structure at vendor you can do as 
`"AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle\\" : "AlexisLefebvre/Bundle/AsyncTweetsBundle/"` which will position your files at 

`vendor/alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle/AlexisLefebvre/Bundle/AsyncTweetsBundle/<your files>`

Comment: @A.L If you want to know more about autoloading or psr0/psr4 you can visit these links that made me clear [Autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and [PSR-4 autoloading support in Composer](http://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer)

Comment: @A.L if your issue has been solved why not select the best answer and mark the question as solved.

Comment: @SanThapa comments from both answers helped me a lot, I have to decide which one helped me most.

Comment: This answer helped me but switching to `psr-4`, as suggested by Cerad, made my bundle worked, that's why I accepted Cerad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `psr-4` in <kbd>composer.json</kbd>:

```
{
    "name" : "alexislefebvre/async-tweets-bundle",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "description" : "PHP Twitter reader for asynchronous reading",
    "keywords" : ["twitter", "reader", "bundle"],
    [...]
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "AlexisLefebvre\\Bundle\\AsyncTweetsBundle\\" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the base bundle class:

```
<?php

namespace AlexisLefebvre\Bundle\AsyncTweetsBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AsyncTweetsBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

I was able to load the bundle in Symfony2 by adding this to <kbd>app/AppKernel.php</kbd>:

```
new AlexisLefebvre\Bundle\AsyncTweetsBundle\AsyncTweetsBundle(),
```